# Fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Firefox extension won't install

Tags: firefox

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu. Now Firefox won't install certain extensions. I cannot install Gnome extension and   Ad Block Plus.

It says it won't install, because the file may be corrupt.

Went into terminal, deleted Firefox, and then reinstalled it. This did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to address two issues here.

**Issue #1 (browser extensions):**

Please take a look at the following link:

[Certificate issue causing add-ons to be disabled or fail to install](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/fixed-certificate-issue-causing-add-ons-to-be-disabled-or-fail-to-install/39047)

Check your Firefox version and install the extension fix for your version or update to the latest version of Firefox. This should enable you to install  Ad Block Plus.

**Issue #2 (GNOME extensions):**

Please make sure you have `gnome-shell-extensions` and `chrome-gnome-shell` installed:

Install them as follows:

1. Install gnome-shell-extensions

   `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions`
2. Install chrome-gnome-shell

   `sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell`

After that:

- Install the Gnome tweaks tool as follows:

  `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`
- Open the GNOME tweaks tool as follows:

  `gnome-tweaks`
- Select extensions from the left side menu and enable them.

Firefox gnome extension should now install easily from this web page:

https://extensions.gnome.org/

You might need to log out and re-log in for the gnome extensions to work.

Comment: I think OP is talking about browser extensions not GNOME extensions since they have AdBlock plus as an example.

Comment: @Kulfy I added this part about browser extensions. Thank you.